# Regex pattern for validation use specific character

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have `@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z \b]+$")` for a string field. If I want this pattern to accept the character `|` how can I change it? And I don't know what is `\b` in the above pattern.

Comment: Just add it: `[a-zA-Z \b|]` the `\b` means a word boundary.

Comment: thanks,and if I have this pattern accept '('and')'how can change it?what is word boundry?

Comment: I've added an answer with it. Consider in accepting it IF it is helpfull to you.

Comment: if I have a string field that I want accept only digit(0-9) is it true this pattern?@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9\b]+$")

Comment: No need for `\b` just `[0-9]+` or `\d+` it also means any digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a backslash "\" for escape '|'.

**\b** represents the word's boundaries.
In other words it marks where words start and end.

Here's [a good text about this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Try use
`@Pattern(regexp = "^[\|a-zA-Z \b]+$")`

Comment: thanks,but if i want this pattern accept three character like'|'and')'and'(',how can seprate them on above pattern

Comment: Just add '(' and ')' chars `@Pattern(regexp = "^[\|\(\)a-zA-Z \b]+$")`

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to your expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z \b|]+$
```

The `\b` means a **word boundary**. There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

As per you question on the comments to add the parenteshis to your expression you just have to add it to the regex expression as:

```
^[a-zA-Z \b|()]+$
```

You should read something on regex it is very usefull as you can see look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html